# Making columns with data in other column in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Hi I'm learning data analysis with Pandas. 
I have a list of companies that look like this.

`Company name
0   Crowdbooster
1   Adsense for native content
2   Palo Alto · Native Advertising
3   Nov ’10
4   299
5   Captricity
6   Democratizing Data Access.
7   Oakland · Data Integration
8   Feb ’11
9   513`

The list is consist of the data such as company name,location,year founded and number of followers in order. What I want to do is to make columns with each information type from the list. Something like this.

```
Company name    Company summary Location    Year founded    Followers 
0   Crowdbooster    Adsense for native content  Palo Alto · Native Advertising  Nov ’10 299
1   Captricity  Democratizing Data Access.  Oakland · Data Integration  Feb ’11 513
```

I first wanted to do this with enumerate() and % to separate information but since data is missing somewhere in the list, it can't work. I want to make data missing as Nan and I have 1000+ data points so about 200 companies.
I was thinking to use the follower's number somehow but I don't know how to do it. 
Could someone tell me a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by follower's number? Do you just want to make a list?

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question so please have a look :)

Comment: You may want to consider a dictionary with a key value pair. In that case, the company name could be the key and and an other, nested dictionary could be the value with the location, year and followers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is a list, you can do this:

Let's say your data is in a text file named `data_points.txt`in the same folder where your `.py` file is. If your raw text looks like in your post (*without the numbers*), you can access this text and create a list like this:

```
with open("data_points.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip("\n")for x in content]
    content = [x.replace("\xa1\xa6", "20") for x in content]
    content = [x.replace("\xa1P", " ") for x in content]
```

When you have your data in a list stored in `content`, you will have many options to manipulate this list based on what you want to do with this data. You can just `print content` if you want the list.

Or, you can turn this `list` into a dictionary by adding this code to the code above:

```
dict_content = {'Company':content[0::5], 'Summary':content[1::5], 'Location':content[2::5], 'Year':content[3::5], 'Followers':content[4::5]}
print dict_content
```

The output will be this:

```
{'Company': ['Crowdbooster', 'Captricity'], 'Year': ['Nov 2010', 'Feb 2011'], 'Followers': ['299', '513'], 'Location': ['Palo Alto   Native Advertising', 'Oakland   Data Integration'], 'Summary': ['Adsense for native content', 'Democratizing Data Access.']}
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I have 1000+ data points.. Do you have a good solution to automate it such as by using loops?

Comment: @user3368526 I edited my answer based on your comment. My answer now shows how you can bring your data into a list.

Comment: @user3368526 I also added code to create a dictionary from the list.